# Does there exist a $\theta$ such that $\text{Log}_{\theta}(z^2-1)$ is holomorphic on the set $|z| > 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find a branch of the complex logarithm $\text{Log}_{\theta}(z^2-1)$ which is holomorphic on the set $|z| > 1$ (which is clearly an open set).

Now $z^2-1$ is a difference of two square which means the original Log can be deconstructed into $\text{Log}_{\alpha}(z-1) + \text{Log}_{\beta}(z+1)$ for some $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$.

Taking $\text{Log}_{\alpha}(z-1)$, I am having trouble finding $\alpha$ such that this Log is holomorphic for all $z \in \mathbb{C}, |z| > 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a branch does not exist. Intuitively, the argument of $\log(z^2+1)$ increases by $4 \pi$ if $z$ moves along a circle $z = r e^{it}$, $0 \le t \le 2 \pi$, so that the logarithm can not even be defined as a continuous function.

A rigorous argument can use the fact that if $f$ is holomorphic in a domain $D \subset \Bbb C$ then its derivative has the property that
$$
 \int_\gamma f'(z) \, dz = 0
$$
for any closed curve $\gamma$ in $D$.

Now if $f(z)$ were a holomorphic branch of the logarithm of $z^2-1$ in $\{ |z| > 1 \}$ then
$$
 f'(z) = \frac{2z}{z^2-1} = \frac{1}{z-1} + \frac{1}{z+1}
$$
had the property that
$$
 \int_\gamma \left( \frac{1}{z-1} + \frac{1}{z+1} \right) \,dz = 0
$$
for any closed curve $\gamma$ in $\{ |z| > 1 \}$. But this is not the case for circles centered at the origin with radius $r > 1$.

Comment: Would this also imply that the function $f(z)=(z^2-1)^\frac{1}{2}$ has no holomorphic branch since the definition of complex powers is based on the associated Log branch?

Comment: @JohnDoe: No. If a function has a holomorphic logarithm then it has a holomorphic square root, but the implication in the other direction may not hold. A simple example is $f(z) = z^2$ for $z \ne 0$. It has a square root, but no logarithm.